# Gulp - Get return value of one task from another

Tags: git, gulp, gulp-inject

My goal is to append the latest git commit into my `index.html` file.

The following task successfully returns the latest git hash (using [gulp-git](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-git)):

```
var git = require('gulp-git');
gulp.task('hash', function() {
   git.revParse({args:'--short HEAD'}, function (err, hash) {
     return hash;
   });
});
```

The following task builds my HTML:

```
var inject = require('inject-string');
gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(inject.append('append git hash here!'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

This successfully appends a string into `index.html` but how do I inject the return value of the `hash` task into the `html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can add a callback method to your hash task so that you can save the result into a variable, to use in your html task. The html task should have the hash task as a dependency also, so that the hash is never undefined. In addition, you should probably use something like [gulp-cheerio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-cheerio) to inject the hash into the output, so that you're not appending the hash outside of the closing html tag.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    git  = require('gulp-git'),
    cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio');

var gitHash;

gulp.task('hash', function(cb) {
  return git.revParse({args:'--short HEAD'}, function(err, hash) {
     gitHash = hash;
     cb();
   });
});

gulp.task('html', ['hash'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(cheerio(function($) {
        $('body').append('<p>' + gitHash + '</p>');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there anything wrong with appending an HTML comment after the closing </html> tag? I know old versions of IE don't like that, but I don't know anything else wrong with it.

Comment: Oh, if it's a *comment* I think it should be OK. :-) Then again a comment should be also fine just after the closing body tag.